# MFC - Posting data via PostMessage to the GUI

Tags: multithreading, mfc, postmessage

I Read a few threads on how passing data from Workerthread to Main window(Dialog), but I still don't understand and still need help.
My workerthread should process some calculations and display the result during each loop to an edit on the GUI. I know, I should use PostMessage but since the calculation I'm doing implies a control element, I don't know how to solve this problem ...

```
 //CWorkerThreadMgr.h manages the second thread
HRESULT Start (HWND hWnd);// from where the workerthread will be started 

 HWND  m_hWnd ;    //Window handle to the UI ;

 HANDLE m_hTread;  //handle of the worker thread

 static UINT WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lptest ); 

static UINT WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lptest ) 

{    
  CWorkerThreadMgr* pCalculateMgr = reinterpret_cast< CWorkerThreadMgr*(lptest);

//The following operation:rand() *m_Slider.GetPos() should

//should be calculated and the result displayed each time in the edit box in the gui

for( UINT uCount = 0; uCount < 40; uCount++ ){ 

pCalculateMgr->rand() *m_Slider.GetPos();//?don't allowed to touch the gui!! 

PostMessage(pCalculateMgr-> m_hWnd, WM_SENDCALCULATED_VALUE,wparam(rand() *m_Slider.GetPos(),0); 
} 
} 

LRESULT CStartCalculationDlg::OnSendCalculatedValue( WPARAM Result, LPARAM )

{ 
    // The resut should be displayed in the edit box

      m_Calculation.Format(_T("%d"),???); 
      SetDlgItemText(IDC_CALCULATION, m_Calculation); 

     return 1; 
} 

void CStartCalculationDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos,CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{ 
  m_SliderValue.Format(_T("%d"),m_Slider.GetPos()); 
  SetDlgItemText(IDC_SLIDER_VALUE,m_SliderValue); 
} 

// Implementation in the CStartCalculationDlg.h 

CWorkerThreadMgr   m_WorkerThreadMgr  //instance of the WorkerThreadMgr 
CSliderCtrl  m_Slider  //member variable of the slider control 
CString m_SliderValue  // member variable of the edit box, where the current value of the 
                       //slider will be displayed 
CString  m_Calculation // member variable of the edit box where the calculated 
                       //result from  the workerthread will be displayed via PostMessage 
afx_msg LRESULT OnSendCalculatedValue( WPARAM, LPARAM ); 
afx_msg void OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
```

The next probem is that, when my slider control is moved and gets a new value, the thread procedure should know it and update the value of the slider. How can I manage to do it?

Comment: can you pass the slider position as a parameter to the thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the slider position from the worker thread, read it in the UI thread and make it available to the worker thread.

I'm really no expert in this field, but I've done some worker threads as explained [here](http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm).

What I would do in your case is create a static variable, like the "running" flag used in the article linked above, to hold the current position of the slider. Then, in the OnHScroll handler set it to the appropriate value.

As long as you only write to that variable from one thread, you should not have synchronization issues.

Answer (score 0):

From worker thread:

```
m_data = foo();
PostMessage(hWndMain, UWM_SOME_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

From UI thread:

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnSomeCustomMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CMyData data = m_pWorker->GetData();
    // Do stuff...
    return 0;
}
```

`GetData` must be guarded by a critical section:

```
CMyData CMyWorker::GetData()
{
     // This critical section is used in the worker thread too, whenever m_data is accessed.
     m_lock.Lock();
     CMyData data = m_data;
     m_lock.Unlock();

     return data;
}
```

See [CCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5zew56b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN.